# jetty package org.json.simple does not exist

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jetty

I have simple servlet to be used by jetty.

This is fragment of my servlet:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

public class Oscar4Servlet extends HttpServlet
{ 
...

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("message", "hello from server");
        out.print(obj);
    }
}
```

After invoking:

```
javac -cp  /usr/share/jetty/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar  Oscar4Servlet.java
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Oscar4Servlet.java:5: error: package org.json.simple does not exist
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
                      ^
Oscar4Servlet.java:6: error: package org.json.simple does not exist
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
```

Although I have `json-simple-1.1.1.jar` (downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/detail?name=json-simple-1.1.1.jar) in my `WEB_INF/lib` directory... Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiling you need to specify the full compilation classpath. So you need to modify your command to:

```
javac -cp  /usr/share/jetty/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:<path-to>/json-simple-1.1.1.jar Oscar4Servlet.java
```

(and of course any other dependencies)

Alternatively, if you now that all your dependencies are in `/some-path/WEB-INF/lib` then you can do:

```
javac -cp  /usr/share/jetty/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/some-path/WEB-INF/lib/* Oscar4Servlet.java
```

Comment: Let me undestand this. If I have to do this, why I have to put my libraries into WEB_INF/libs? Is that only a convention? Can I keep libraries, that my servelt uses, wherever I want and it doesn't really matter?

Comment: I would expect that storing jars in WEB-INF/lib helps (java or jetty, I don't know) to find these files and use them when necessary.

Comment: Or use a build tool like Apache Maven, that will manage your build classpath and WEB-INF/lib for you from 1 declared set of `<dependencies>` defined in only 1 place.

Comment: @mnowotka putting libraries in `WEB-INF/libs` only helps for runtime dependencies, not compile time. This BTW is one of the reasons that IDEs and dependency management tools like Maven are popular.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - can I then compile my servlet in such a way, that it would load dependencies in runtime?

Comment: @mnowotka No, because the compiler needs access to those classes at compile time.